# Why is S4 inheritance lost between environments?

Tags: r, inheritance, environment, r-s4

Suppose I have a class `MyClass` defined as follows:

```
setClass(
    "MyClass", 
    slots = c(message = "character"), 
    validity = function(object) { T })
```

If I create an instance of it, `inherits` works as expected:

```
myInstance <- new("MyClass", message = "Hello")

inherits(myInstance, "MyClass")
```

> TRUE

However, it doesn't work after I put the instance into an environment and bring it back again:

```
e <- new.env(hash = T, parent = emptyenv())

assign("MyInstance", myInstance, envir = e)

inherits(mget("MyInstance", envir = e), "MyClass")
```

> FALSE

But the data is still there:

```
mget("MyInstance", envir = e)
```

> $MyInstance
>   An object of class "MyClass"
>   Slot "message":
>   [1] "Hello"

How can I tell R to maintain my S4 classes even when saving and loading instances between environments?

Comment: did you try `mget("MyInstance", envir = e)` ? and see what is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mget` returns a named list of the objects requested.  You're actually examining the list.  To examine the object you need to extract it from the output of `mget`.  Alternatively just use `get` which returns just the object of interest.

`mget` is useful when requesting a bunch of objects but if you just want one then `get` is just fine.